# Pandas get cumulative sum after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame : basically each row being a transaction carried out by one customer on a day. 
there are multiple transactions by same customer on same day and on different dates. I want to get a column for a customers number of previous visits.

```
id  date   purchase 

id1 date1  $10    

id1 date1  $50    

id1 date2  $30     

id2 date1  $10     

id2 date1  $10     

id3 date3  $10
```

after adding visits column:

```
id  date   purchase  visit

id1 date1  $10         0 

id1 date1  $50         0

id1 date2  $30         1

id2 date1  $10         0

id2 date2  $10         1

id2 date3  $10         2
```

I tried doing

```
df.visits = 1 
df.visits = df.groupby([id, date], as_index=False)[visits].transform(cumsum)
```

but it gives cumulative sum per transaction.
how to get same value per day but iterate for next day.. ??

Comment: the input df looks wrong, the second last row date should be date2? and the id3 should be id2?

Comment: yup my bad. but you already gave the answer, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you need:

```
df['visit']=df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
print(df)
```

---

```
    id   date purchase  visit
0  id1  date1      $10      0
1  id1  date1      $50      0
2  id1  date2      $30      1
3  id2  date1      $10      0
4  id2  date2      $10      1
5  id2  date3      $10      2
```

Comment: could you give me an equivalent sql query for this to understand it better

Comment: @SaleemAhmed i am no expert in sql, but if you have a look at the `pd.factorize()` docs, it will help. basically the idea is, identify each unique occurrences with a integer value(since python starts with 0, it helps your usecase) :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with Categorical:

```
df['visit'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].transform(lambda x: pd.Categorical(x).codes)
```

Comment: Wouldnt this `df['visit'] = pd.Categorical(df.date).codes` be sufficient in your approach?

Comment: no, the categories need to be set at the customer level. if a customer never visit the store at date1 but only at date2, date2 need to be 0